# can't convert string to int "String can't be coerced into Fixnum"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am using Ancestry gem and ActiveAdmin. I need to use the depth method to indent select option. I believe depth is a string so I wanted to convert into an int so that I could multiply by a space. Like so:

```
    form do |f|


    f.inputs "Category" do

      f.input :ancestry, :as => :select, :collection => ItemsCategory.all.map {|u| [u.depth.to_i * "" + u.name  , u.id]}

      f.input :name
    end
    f.actions
    f.semantic_errors
  end
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: What is `f`? What is `ItemsCategory`? What is `depth`? What is `name`? What is `id`?

Comment: `u.depth * "  "` this causing the problem. What is `depth`?

Comment: What does it mean to multiply a string by a string?

Comment: I think it maybe an array

Comment: @sawa How can I accomplish what I am trying to do with that code without getting the error int eh title. I updated the code for context of f. depth is an Ancestry method. It's how many levels this node is from the root

Comment: Omg, he just take my code and change to it.

Comment: @isea why you change your code to reproduce the error, after it works when you used mine?

Comment: I'm not sure I know what you talking about

Comment: @isea, you have updated the code in your question, which now doesn't raise anymore the error in the title.

Comment: No, I updated it to reflect my problem appropriately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming that `u.depth` is a `Fixnum`.

The problem is `u.depth * "  "`. You can't multiply a `Fixnum` by a `String`, it just doesn't make sense. The other way around is ok, though:

```
3 * "a"
# => TypeError: String can't be coerced into Fixnum
"a" * 3
# => "aaa"
```

If, as you say:

> I believe depth is a string so I wanted to convert into an int

Then you can just do `u.depth.to_i` (will return `0` if the string is not a number).

Comment: the problem is, I want the indention to be a space for every node level deep. i.e. depth = 1 _ depth = 2 __

Comment: "Then you can just do u.depth.to_i (will return 0 if the string is not a number)." The string is a number

Comment: uhm... my answer did answer exactly that. But now you have updated the code in your question, so I'm not sure what you're looking for.